# "flutter pub publish" complains "pubspec.yaml should have an email address" but documentation says "verified publisher" can avoid using personal email

Tags: flutter

How are pub.dev package authors omitting the "author" field in their pubspec.yaml files when it's required by the "flutter packages pub pub" command?

I'm trying to upload my first package and I've wasted hours on this problem: [Online package publishing docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing) say:

> You can avoid having pub.dev display your personal email address. Instead, pub.dev displays displays the publisher domain and contact address.

yet when I try to omit my email address in pubspec.yaml:

```
author: My Name
homepage: https://my.github.repo.home.page
```

flutter -v pub publish complains:

> - Author "My Name" in pubspec.yaml should have an email address   (e.g. "name ").

Yet I see lots of new packages being uploaded every hour with no author field AT ALL in their pubspec.yaml files.  How are they doing that?  How come they can upload without an author and email and I can't?

I've authenticated my Internet domain and created a "verified publisher" this morning but one thing I don't understand is how to communicate my publisher info to my package... maybe that is the missing piece?